# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory LD_LIBRARY_PATH appropriately set

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I see this error when I try to install tensorflow-gpu using pip install on a blank AWS machine with Ubuntu 16.04.

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when i do locate libcublas, i see the following (Which implies my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set)

```
(tensorflow) ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-124:~$ locate libcublas
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/doc/man/man7/libcublas.7
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/doc/man/man7/libcublas.so.7
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas.so
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas.so.9.0
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas.so.9.0.176
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas.so.9.0.282
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas.so.9.0.333
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas_device.a
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas_static.a
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/stubs/libcublas.so
/usr/share/man/man7/libcublas.7
/usr/share/man/man7/libcublas.so.7
```

I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH and CUDA_PATH as required. I am totally stumped with this error message. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: add your path too and LD_PATH too, probably tour LD_PATH is set /usr/local/cuda//lib64/ instead /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/

Comment: So, I fixed this. Turns out looking at
 `ldconfig -v | grep *libcublas*` suggested that it was not finding the libraries. So, I manually edited /etc/ldconfig.so related paths and it works okay. I have to admit this was not fun and quite arduous. Not a great move from a stable package maker.